# Laravel Eloquent Validation request's items field foreach

Tags: php, json, laravel, validation, eloquent

I am writing Validator in Laravel, and so I am getting json format request.

I have written validate logic for main json's fields such as id, name... Now I have items array of objects in json, and I need to validate each item from this array which is passed.

Here's example of json request: https://api.myjson.com/bins/ob3lh

And here's my validator so far:

```
 private function update()
  {
    return [
      'id' => 'required',
      'place_id' => 'required',
      'place_table_id' => 'required',
      'user_id' => 'required',
      'seen' => 'required',
      'state' => 'required',
      'number' => 'required',
      'date' => 'required',
      'price' => 'required',
      'table_number' => 'required',
      'note' => 'required',
    ];
  }
```

How can I add simply for example nested validator which will validate each of items object?

Comment: Convert object to array and then validate

Comment: Like `"array.*.obj_name" => "required"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define nested validation rules like this:

```
private function update()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'required',
        'place_id' => 'required',
        'place_table_id' => 'required',
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'seen' => 'required',
        'state' => 'required',
        'number' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'table_number' => 'required',
        'note' => 'required',
        'items' => 'required|array|min:1',
        'items.*.id' => 'required',
        'items.*.name' => 'required',
        'items.*.amount' => 'required',
        'items.*.price' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

You can find more info on this in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: does "*" take care of array index or will just a path of dynamic

Comment: This looks great, but I would need just one more thing. How to get this done  no matter of array items count? Validation fails if i pass "items" : [], but works when i pass "items" : "[]".

Comment: It only validates existing items. If you want to ensure there are always at least 1 or more items you can add the following line: `'items' => 'array|min:1',`

Comment: @RojVroemen 'items' => 'array|min:0' finally fixed my thing. Thanks for a response!